# Horizontal scrollbar in a Table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Due to my many columns and the long entries in those columns, I wanted to implement a horizontal scrollbar in my table.

The only options I found in the API references was this one, to add a property to my table:

```
navigationMode="Scrollbar"
```

but this seems to work only for vertical scrollbar not a horizontal one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your table into a `sap.m.ScrollContainer`. Add your table to the container's `<content>` aggregation. This will make your table scrollable. You can control the vertical and horizontal scrollbar visibility by properties `horizontal` and `vertical`.

[API link.](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ScrollContainer.html)

**Edit:** An example:

```
<Page title="{i18n>title}">
    <content>
        <ScrollContainer>
            <content>
                <Table>
                    <columns>
                        <Column width="1000px">
                            <Text text="1" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column width="1000px">
                            <Text text="2" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column width="1000px" >
                            <Text text="3" />
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="1" />
                                <Text text="2" />
                                <Text text="3" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
            </content>
        </ScrollContainer>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Comment: I added `xmlns:scrollbar="sap.m.ScrollContainer"` and set my table into `<scrollbar:content>` but its not working because of this Error: **ncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/ScrollContainer/content.js' from ../../resources/sap/m/ScrollContainer/content.js: 404 - Not Found**

Comment: `<content>` is not part of the `ScrollContainer`, it's part of the `m` namespace. So if you've already defined the `sap.m` namespace, use this for the ScrollContainer. If not, create an `xmlns:m="sap.m"` namespace and use `m:ScrollContainer` and `<m:content>`.

Comment: my bad, sorry corrected it but its just not working now my table loads the same way as earlier, without scrollbar

Comment: It's working at my side. What kind of table are using? sap.m.Table? Make sure that sum of column widths are more than the screen size. I attached an example XML snippet.

Comment: I'm using sap.ui.table

Comment: had to just fix the column widths with px unit instead of % and the ui.table will implement by itself a scrollbar pretty cool